# how to join two columns from one table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

table name library;

```
id    item    price
1     book    13$
2     book    0
3     book    0
4     book    12$
5     PEN     0
6     PEN     5$
7     PEN     0
```

Is that possible to get the below result from table Library

```
id   Item    price
1    book    13$
4    book    12$
5    Pen     0
7    Pen     0
```

thanks for helping

Comment: What are the rules for the result set?

Comment: what is the logic behind getting that two book and pen in result table???

Comment: As @puncoz suggested, describe more about your logic and show what you tried so far.

Comment: Please read how to create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. What i'm missing in particular is - What have u tried so far? What errors/problems do you face? Do you may have codesnippets that help understand your question? Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Please attach ur query....!! Welcome to so.. Visit : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use a `where` clause:

```
where (item = book and price > 0) or
      (item = pen and price = 0)
```

I'm not 100% sure that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact result in the question, use double quotations (`" "`) for titles.

For `id >= 5` take item value as initcapped.

In where condition use single quotations(`' '`), evidently seems that item column is of `string` type, and price is `alpha-numeric`(`0,12$ ..` etc.)

```
select id "id", decode(sign(id-4),1,initcap(item),item) "Item", price "price"
  from library
 where (item = 'book' and price != '0') or (item = 'PEN' and price = '0')
```